# Flutter openai api voice assistant app. Can't get text text response

Tags: android, flutter, openai-api

This android app get voice input transcribed to text and send it to shatgpt. Answer from chat defines whether or not this question is about art or just a regular and depending on the answer sends it to dallE or chatgpt.

After a long work i fixed everything about dallE and it get and image on screen, but i still can't get response on regular question. Firstly i think it sends multiple inputs every time it updates variable with recognized words and because of that instantly drains limit for 3rpm. Secondly, whenewer i manage to get some sort of coded answers (presumably caused by different language voice input). Also, if it matters, i debug on phisycal device.

Here is the part that triggers exception in openai.dart file:

```
Future<String> chatGPTAPI(String prompt) async {
    messages.add({
      'role': 'user',
      'content': prompt,
    });
    try {
      final res = await http.post(
        Uri.parse('https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions'),
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Authorization': 'Bearer $OpenAIAPIKey',
        },
        body: jsonEncode({
          "model": "gpt-3.5-turbo",
          "messages": messages,
        }),
      );

      if (res.statusCode == 200) {
        String content =
            jsonDecode(res.body)['choices'][0]['message']['content'];
        content = content.trim();

        messages.add({
          'role': 'assistant',
          'content': content,
        });
        return content;
      }
      return 'GPT';
    } catch (e) {
      return e.toString();
    }
  }
```

That's the part about defining questions nature also from openai.dart:

```
Future<String> isArtPromptAPI(String prompt) async {
    try {
      final res = await http.post(
        Uri.parse('https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions'),
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Authorization': 'Bearer $OpenAIAPIKey',
        },
        body: jsonEncode({
          "model": "gpt-3.5-turbo",
          "messages": [
            {
              'role': 'user',
              'content':
                  'Is this question about art ? $prompt . Answer only with yes or no.',
            }
          ],
        }),
      );
      print(res.body);
      if (res.statusCode == 200) {
        String content =
            jsonDecode(res.body)['choices'][0]['message']['content'];
        content = content.trim();

        switch (content) {
          case 'Yes':
          case 'yes':
          case 'Yes.':
          case 'yes.':
            final res = await dallEAPI(prompt);
            return res;
          default:
            final res = await chatGPTAPI(prompt);
            return res;
        }
      }
      return 'Something with first prompt';
    } catch (e) {
      return e.toString();
    }
  }
```

Debug console output:

```
Connecting to VM Service at ws://127.0.0.1:49781/oQAgT8h0OYw=/ws
D/BluetoothHeadset(15864): Binding service...
I/flutter (15864): speech recog init: true
D/DecorView[](15864): onWindowFocusChanged hasWindowFocus true
I/flutter (15864): FloatingActionButton pressed
I/flutter (15864): last words updated:
I/flutter (15864): last words updated:
I/flutter (15864): last words updated:
I/flutter (15864): last words updated:
I/flutter (15864): last words updated:
I/flutter (15864): last words updated: What
I/flutter (15864): last words updated: What is
I/flutter (15864): last words updated: What is
I/flutter (15864): last words updated:
I/flutter (15864): {
I/flutter (15864):   "id": "chatcmpl-7SommSmeQHX8BUIlYsxFw4WVoXQde",
I/flutter (15864):   "object": "chat.completion",
I/flutter (15864):   "created": 1687102760,
I/flutter (15864):   "model": "gpt-3.5-turbo-0301",
I/flutter (15864):   "usage": {
I/flutter (15864):     "prompt_tokens": 24,
I/flutter (15864):     "completion_tokens": 17,
I/flutter (15864):     "total_tokens": 41
I/flutter (15864):   },
I/flutter (15864):   "choices": [
I/flutter (15864):     {
I/flutter (15864):       "message": {
I/flutter (15864):         "role": "assistant",
I/flutter (15864):         "content": "I cannot provide an accurate response as the question is missing. Please provide the question."
I/flutter (15864):       },
I/flutter (15864):       "finish_reason": "stop",
I/flutter (15864):       "index": 0
I/flutter (15864):     }
I/flutter (15864):   ]
I/flutter (15864): }
I/flutter (15864): {
I/flutter (15864):   "id": "chatcmpl-7SommhwdHszaqrCSeXAu7VvSWC9P9",
I/flutter (15864):   "object": "chat.completion",
I/flutter (15864):   "created": 1687102760,
I/flutter (15864):   "model": "gpt-3.5-turbo-0301",
I/flutter (15864):   "usage": {
I/flutter (15864):     "prompt_tokens": 23,
I/flutter (15864):     "completion_tokens": 14,
I/flutter (15864):     "total_tokens": 37
I/flutter (15864):   },
I/flutter (15864):   "choices": [
I/flutter (15864):     {
I/flutter (15864):       "message": {
I/flutter (15864):         "role": "assistant",
I/flutter (15864):         "content": "It is impossible to answer the question without any context or information provided."
I/flutter (15864):       },
I/flutter (15864):       "finish_reason": "stop",
I/flutter (15864):       "index": 0
I/flutter (15864):     }
I/flutter (15864):   ]
I/flutter (15864): }
D/TTS     (15864): Utterance ID has been stopped: 465519ac-d625-413a-aca3-3ab20257bf44. Interrupted: true
I/flutter (15864): {
I/flutter (15864):   "id": "chatcmpl-7SommDn3Y9LHq7x2GvuLVg8v2Ieo1",
I/flutter (15864):   "object": "chat.completion",
I/flutter (15864):   "created": 1687102760,
I/flutter (15864):   "model": "gpt-3.5-turbo-0301",
I/flutter (15864):   "usage": {
I/flutter (15864):     "prompt_tokens": 24,
I/flutter (15864):     "completion_tokens": 24,
I/flutter (15864):     "total_tokens": 48
I/flutter (15864):   },
I/flutter (15864):   "choices": [
I/flutter (15864):     {
I/flutter (15864):       "message": {
I/flutter (15864):         "role": "assistant",
I/flutter (15864):         "content": "I'm sorry, but you haven't provided a question to answer with a yes or no. Please provide a question."
I/flutter (15864):       },
I/flutter (15864):       "finish_reason": "stop",
I/flutter (15864):       "index": 0
I/flutter (15864):     }
I/flutter (15864):   ]
I/flutter (15864): }
D/TTS     (15864): Utterance ID has started: 0f5c1052-60ec-4de9-8d8e-6ce882617db9
D/TTS     (15864): Utterance ID has been stopped: 0f5c1052-60ec-4de9-8d8e-6ce882617db9. Interrupted: true
D/TTS     (15864): Utterance ID has started: fcd6ec20-d833-47c5-ae5e-70eab6333830
D/TTS     (15864): Utterance ID has completed: fcd6ec20-d833-47c5-ae5e-70eab6333830
```

[And this is the return that i managed to get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N9vsO.jpg)
At this point i don't know what to do about it and this is my last resort. Thank you in advance.

I tried to go from chat completion to davinci model, but it didn't work out.
Tried to play around with creating isRecording variables to prevent it from multiple inputs.
Browsed through a lot of questions and documentation.
Honestly can't even remember everything because my brain is already overheated.